# Changing CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, djcelery

I'm have two django apps using the same database. Both using celery and having own `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE`. Is there a way to distinct which tasks should be run in proper celery worker ? now tasks from both apps  are scheduled in the same worker.
The reason of that is (?) `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER` to `'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'`. I couldn't find any approach/scheduler not using Database. As a broker I'm using redis (local/different for each app) so tasks from outside of CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE are working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define two queues in `CELERY_QUEUES` setting and assign one queue to each celerybeat using `--queues=queue1` parameter.

You can assing task to specific queue using options:

```
'options': {'queue': 'queue1'},
```